# Using a class' method as default parameter in Swift

Tags: swift

I want to create a class' method that takes some parameters and a function. And I want that function parameter to have a default value. So I'm doing:

```swift
class Calculator {

    func operate(n1: Int, n2: Int, _ f: ((Int, Int) -> Int)? = add) -> Int {
        return (f ?? add)(n1, n2)
    }

    func add(n1: Int, n2: Int) -> Int {
        return n1 + n2
    }
}
```

Here, `f` is a function parameter that can be passed (or not, as it is optional). I want add to be the default value for f, so if you do:

```swift
Calculator().operate(n1: 10, n2: 20)
// not passing f causes add to be called
```

**Problem:** this does not compile, it's telling me that the correct type for `f` should be: `(Calculator) -> (Int, Int) -> Int`. That is: `add` is a method of class Calculator, which makes perfect sense.

But **is there a way to express that method as a function?**

I can define a external function like:

```swift
func externalAdd(n1: Int, n2: Int) -> Int {
    return n1 + n2
}
```

Then everything works as expected is I change the default value of `f`:

```swift
class Calculator {

    func operate(n1: Int, n2: Int, _ f: ((Int, Int) -> Int)? = externalAdd) -> Int {
        return (f ?? add)(n1, n2)
    }

    func add(n1: Int, n2: Int) -> Int {
        return n1 + n2
    }
}
```

Ideas? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
func operate(n1: Int, n2: Int, _ f: ((Int, Int) -> Int)? = add) -> Int
```

`add` is evaluated as `Calculator.add` which has the type

```
 (Calculator) -> (Int, Int) -> Int
```

as explained in [Instance Methods are “Curried” Functions in Swift](https://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/).

One option is to use `nil` as the default value (since you do optional chaining anyway later):

```
class Calculator {

    func operate(n1: Int, n2: Int, _ f: ((Int, Int) -> Int)? = nil) -> Int {
        return (f ?? add)(n1, n2)
    }

    func add(n1: Int, n2: Int) -> Int {
        return n1 + n2
    }
}
```

Another option is to make the default function a `static` method, and the function parameter non-optional:

```
class Calculator {

    func operate(n1: Int, n2: Int, _ f: ((Int, Int) -> Int) = add) -> Int {
        return f(n1, n2)
    }

    static func add(n1: Int, n2: Int) -> Int {
        return n1 + n2
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a possibility, sure. I'll have to add a regular method that calls that static one. Surprised there's no other way to express that. After all, that method IS a function with the correct signature.

Comment: @DiegoFreniche, instance method has different signature, which is not "correct". All instance methods has are functions that take `self` and return function. So your `add` is `(Calculator) -> (Int, Int) -> Int` instead of just `(Int, Int) -> Int`. And you can actually call any instance method as `Type.method(instance)(params)` instead of `instance.method(params)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you try this:

```
class Calculator {
  var addFunction: ((Int, Int) -> Int) {
    return add
  }

  func operate(n1: Int, n2: Int, _ f: ((Int, Int) -> Int)? = addFunction) -> Int {
    func add(n1: Int, n2: Int) -> Int {
      return n1 + n2
    }

    return (f ?? add)(n1, n2)
  }

  func add(n1: Int, n2: Int) -> Int {
    return n1 + n2
  }
}
```

The compiler error will be "Cannot use instance member 'addFunction' as a default parameter".

The reason is that in swift you cannot use instance variables in function declarations.

Hope it helps